# What's the problem in this while statement?

Tags: java, while-loop

so I'm a beginner I just started like 3 days ago and I'm trying to make a While statement in java and I can't seem to find a way to make a loop without not having a user input again in the while block, My idea in this code is to ask the user for the wanted operation and if it's empty or non of the operations available, the program will give him an error message then loop the program

```
import java.util.*;

public class calc{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("1.Sum\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division");
        int oper = sc.nextInt();
        while (oper > 4 || oper < 1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
            System.out.println("1.Sum\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division");
            int oper = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing really wrong is the second `int oper = sc.nextInt();`. You've already got a variable `oper` in scope, you can't declare another.

Remove the `int`.

You might instead want to consider restructuring the loop, so you don't have to repeat the messages and the reading from the scanner:

```
int oper;
while (true) {
  System.out.println("1.Sum\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division");
  oper = sc.nextInt();

  if (oper >= 1 && oper <= 4) {
    break;
  }

  System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
}
```

Comment: why did we put in the While braces "true" in your code, what is it supposed to mean, btw amazing answer and nice way to simplify my code I really love it

Comment: The `while` loop loops until the condition becomes false. Since `true` can never become false, that means the loop will keep on looping forever - at least, until you `break` out of it (or return, or throw, or invoke `System.exit`).